# Ambiguous behavior of standard output stream

Tags: java, arguments, output, outputstream

I want to know why the line 5 and line 6 of the following code differs in output?

```
  /*1*/      class A
  /*2*/      {
  /*3*/         public static void main(String[] args)
  /*4*/         {
  /*5*/             System.out.println(3+5+"Message");
  /*6*/             System.out.println("Message"+3+5);
                }
        }
```

**Output:**

```
8Message
Message35
```

Why the second line code has `35` and not `8` instead of `35`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
System.out.println(3+5+"Message");
```

Expression is evaluate from left to right. Left and right `+` is integer hence addition and than right of `+` is string concatenation.
Let's break it this way `(3+5+"Message")`

```
3=integer
+=operator
5=integer

(3)integer (+) (5)integer = (8)integer,
```

And than on next pass

```
(8)integer (+) ("Message")String = (8Message)String
```

Therefore output is `8Message`

```
System.out.println("Message"+3+5);
```

Here from begining around `+` operator there's a string hence concatenation takes place.
Hence the output is `Message35`

Answer (score 0):

[Operator precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

> All binary operators except for the assignment operators are evaluated from left to right; assignment operators are evaluated right to left.

The operator   + is evaluated left-to-right.

That is why in first case it is addition. And in second case it is String concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

```
Like the post above sais, you have operator precedence. Everything is evaluated from left to right.


System.out.println(3+5+"Message");
```

is translated to

```
System.out.println((3+5)+"Message"); So first the addition happens and the result concatenates with the string.
```

In the other case:

```
System.out.println("Message"+3+5);
```

is translated to

```
System.out.println(("Message"+3)+5);
```

You have a String and a number Message3 + 5 = Message53

I hope this clears it :)